# setInterval on mouseenter and clear interval on mouseleave

Tags: jquery, setinterval, mouseenter, mouseleave, clearinterval

I'm using setInterval to create a diy slideshow that starts on mouseenter using this tutorial :
https://www.amideveloper.com/how-to-start-slideshow-on-hover-image-in-jquery/

It works fine, but I would like the slideshow to stop on mouseleave by using clearInterval.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong has my Interval is not cleared and the slideshow won't stop...

here is my code :

JQUERY

```
$(".fadeInOut > div:gt(0)").hide();

function change_div() {

  $(".fadeInOut > div:first").fadeOut(0).next().fadeIn(0).end().appendTo(".fadeInOut");

}

$(".fadeInOut").mouseenter(function(){

    myVar = setInterval(change_div, 600);
  change_div();

});

$(".fadeInOut").mouseleave(function(){

  clearInterval(myVar);

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="fadeInOut">
    <div><img src="https://www.amideveloper.com/wp-content/themes/amideveloper/slide/slider-1.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.amideveloper.com/wp-content/themes/amideveloper/slide/slider-2.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://www.amideveloper.com/wp-content/themes/amideveloper/slide/slider-3.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fadeInOut > div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

here's a link to a jsfidlle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0ysg3r67/

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your fiddle is working as you describe for me (latest Chrome on Win10). Although I'd suggest declaring `myVar` explicitly in the right scope rather than implicitly making it a global.

Comment: The issue is that your logic around swapping out slides is causing the mouseenter to re-trigger, creating multiple intervals.

Comment: @Taplar which browser are you testing with? In Chrome I only get each console.log once (per event) in the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Lpz746hq/

Comment: @Taplar but the listener is set on the div containing the images.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Firefox, I added a console log to the mouseenter and leave, and hovered over the element.  The start log fired every time the slide changes  https://jsfiddle.net/h5vLteag/1/

Comment: However, I agree this issue does not appear to exist in Chrome.

Comment: @Taplar,  you're right, I'm using Firefox... on Chrome it works fine... any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myVar;

$(".fadeInOut").mouseenter(function(){
  clearInterval(myVar);
  myVar = setInterval(change_div, 600);
  change_div();
});
```

Something with your slide transitions is causing the mouseenter to retrigger, creating multiple intervals.  To safeguard against this, attempt to clear the interval before creating a new one.

As an alternative, instead of moving around slides, you can simply tag the one that is visible, and use that to know which slide should be shown next.  This appears to resolve the issue with Firefox triggering the mouseenter over and over.

```js
var myVar;
var $slides = $('.fadeInOut > div');

$(".fadeInOut > div:not(.current)").hide();

function change_div() {
 var $current = $slides.filter('.current');
  var $next = ($current.next().length ? $current.next() : $slides.first());
  
  $current.fadeOut(0).removeClass('current');
  $next.addClass('current').fadeIn(0);
}

$(".fadeInOut").mouseenter(function(){
 console.log('start');

 myVar = setInterval(change_div, 600);
  change_div();

});

$(".fadeInOut").mouseleave(function(){
  console.log('stop');
  clearInterval(myVar);

});
```

```css
.fadeInOut > div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fadeInOut">
 <div class="current"><img src="https://www.amideveloper.com/wp-content/themes/amideveloper/slide/slider-1.jpg"></div>
 <div><img src="https://www.amideveloper.com/wp-content/themes/amideveloper/slide/slider-2.jpg"></div>
 <div><img src="https://www.amideveloper.com/wp-content/themes/amideveloper/slide/slider-3.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with trying to clear an interval before making a new one.  Especially when you are overlaying the variable that points to the old one.

Comment: sure I know, I get it... but I don't understand why it doesn't work right on firefox...

Comment: Most likely the `.appendTo(".fadeInOut")` is the cause, as that operation is going to detach the element and reattach it to the same element.  For some reason, Firefox is considering that to trigger the mouseenter event again, and Chrome is not.

Comment: @mmdwc  that does indeed appear to be the root issue.  I've added a snippet with a modified way of performing the slides, that does not re-trigger the event in Firefox.